# CORS request structure is hard to follow, can you help explain it more?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

A server is looking for CORS requests to get data sets, but the issue is that i dont know how to create a proper CORS request using $.ajax.

There is 1 Stackoverflow post which helps describe it: [How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

There is a Wikipedia Article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

But all in all, despite it telling me that information, i have issues understanding how to properly do the request.

In the first  link, it just does a

```
$.post(SERVER_URL, {file_url:"asfd"}, function(e){console.log(e);});
```

I think my confusion is that i was thinking that i would need to do 2 requests.  One which does the initial hand-shaking, and then the other which takes the result of the first plus some other data.

Could someone help me create a proper CORS requet using jQuery OR Javascript?  It seems like i dont quite understand how the structure of it is.  If there are certain flags i need to use.  I am used to doing simple JSONP requests, which since it is not CORS get the data, but then fail.

Thank you.

**EDIT** I have a post which is related that was resolved.   The Result was JSON, not JSONP, but the server department said CORS was set up on the machines so i figured i did the syntax wrong.  Here is the link: [AJAX request returns 200OK but fails despite return data being JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748647/ajax-request-returns-200ok-but-fails-despite-return-data-being-json)

Comment: The browser does that for you automatically.

Comment: So if i do an **$.ajax()** request, it will auto do CORS if JSONP doesnt work?  It seeems like when i was doing my ajax call, it returned ERROR even though the errorcode was success.  I figured it didnt do it via CORS, and just did it as JSONP.

Comment: The server has to support CORS for CORS to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest going through the MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Both theory and practical examples are explained.

Comment: perfect!  Examples help a lot.